# Building Yocto Linux Image with my own program inside of Image

Tags: linux, build, yocto

I've successfully built Yocto and can run the Linux enviroment on my embedded hardware.  However, I am stuck on where how to place my program into the Image so that when I run the Linux environment on the embedded hardware, I can run my program. I've been trying to find the answer at https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html , but so far I am either missing something or not fully understanding the documentation. Does anyone have any ideas or examples to guide me to the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your own bitbake recipe for building and including the application in the image. See a hello world example [here](http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Hello_World).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah to install your own program binary into the OS image you need to write your own recipe and helloworld is best example to refer.

You can get more additional info like create own layer, create own image and install own code binary into OS image please have a look at https://github.com/prashantdivate/meta-sirius